# Review Rejected because I marked it as a duplicate

Tags: support

[How to split a string that appears twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348835/how-to-split-a-string-that-appears-twice) I reviewed as a duplicate of:

[SQL Server 2000: remove duplicates from comma-separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882509/sql-server-2000-remove-duplicates-from-comma-separated-string)

Why was this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're asking very *similar* questions, but the answers to each are *very* different, given that the problem set is *very* different.

One's asking to remove dupes in a comma-separated line in a specific way, and the other is asking to remove repeated strings from query results.  Both have different approaches in their solution (even if the crux of the problem is similar), and to a passer-by, one couldn't be considered a duplicate of the other unless a more general answer were to happen by.

As to why you failed the audit?  I could spin out some spiel about how the above factored in, but it really doesn't; the question simply was well-received by the community and *hadn't* been voted for closure yet, so the system believed you to be mistaking this one for a question of lesser quality.

This is one of those review pitfalls that you've got to be careful for.  I would take from this a closer look at how you view duplicates.  Just because they question is *similar* doesn't mean that the answers can automatically translate through.  It is largely the case that they *can*, but you should still be careful when examining questions for closure like this anyway.